# What is buffering in mongoose model function call?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting started with MongoDB and I was reading the mongoose documentation when I found this:

> Mongoose lets you start using your models immediately, without waiting for mongoose to establish a connection to MongoDB.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', {useNewUrlParser: true});
const MyModel = mongoose.model('Test', new Schema({ name: String }));
// Works
MyModel.findOne(function(error, result) { /* ... */ });
```

> That's because mongoose buffers model function calls internally. This buffering is convenient, but also a common source of confusion. Mongoose will not throw any errors by default if you use a model without connecting.

---

What's `buffering` in this context?

Also, what does the author mean to say by the following sentence:

> This buffering is convenient, but also a common source of confusion.

Why is buffering convenient? And why/how is it a common source of confusion? I'm totally not being able to understand any of this. Any insights into this would be really appreciated thanks in advance!!

Comment: I guess all queries are put into a queue, which are then processed when the connection is established.

Comment: I think they mean "queuing", not "buffering".